# Partition a Set into k Disjoint Subset

Tags: algorithm, set, sum, subset, data-partitioning

Give a Set `S`, partition the set into `k` disjoint subsets such that the difference of their sums is minimal.

say, `S = {1,2,3,4,5}` and `k = 2`, so `{ {3,4}, {1,2,5} }` since their sums `{7,8}` have minimal difference. For `S = {1,2,3}, k = 2` it will be `{{1,2},{3}}` since difference in sum is `0`.

The problem is similar to *The Partition Problem* from *The Algorithm Design Manual*. Except *Steven Skiena* discusses a method to solve it **without** rearrangement.

I was going to try Simulated Annealing. So i wondering, if there was a better method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem is *dope*. I'll definitely think about it = )

Comment: What do you mean by 'without rearrangement'?

Comment: @spinning_plate, In the skiena version, the order of the elements mattered, you couldn't shuffle them up....so it wasn't a "set" persay.

Comment: How do you define the "difference of their sums" when k > 2?

Comment: @mbeckish, I'd say something like max( sum(A)-sum(B) ) for all A,B

Comment: @spinning_plate - So you're trying to minimize the largest difference between 2 subsets' sums?

Comment: @mbeckish - sure, or we could do something like sum( avg(all X) - y ) for all y.  It might matter for certain functions ( like silly optimizations like min( avg(max(subset)) for each subset(y) )  for all y, but for those two I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudo-polytime algorithm for a knapsack can be used for `k=2`.  The best we can do is sum(S)/2. Run the knapsack algorithm

```
for s in S:
    for i in 0 to sum(S):
        if arr[i] then arr[i+s] = true;
```

then look at sum(S)/2, followed by sum(S)/2 +/- 1, etc.

For 'k>=3' I believe this is NP-complete, like the 3-partition problem.

The simplest way to do it for k>=3 is just to brute force it, here's one way, not sure if it's the fastest or cleanest.

```
import copy
arr = [1,2,3,4]

def t(k,accum,index):
    print accum,k
    if index == len(arr):
        if(k==0):
            return copy.deepcopy(accum);
        else:
            return [];

    element = arr[index];
    result = []

    for set_i in range(len(accum)):
        if k>0:
            clone_new = copy.deepcopy(accum);
            clone_new[set_i].append([element]);
            result.extend( t(k-1,clone_new,index+1) );

        for elem_i in range(len(accum[set_i])):
            clone_new = copy.deepcopy(accum);
            clone_new[set_i][elem_i].append(element)
            result.extend( t(k,clone_new,index+1) );

    return result

print t(3,[[]],0);
```

Simulated annealing might be good, but since the 'neighbors' of a particular solution aren't really clear,  a genetic algorithm might be better suited to this.  You'd start out by randomly picking a group of subsets and 'mutate' by moving numbers between subsets.

Answer (score 0):

If the sets are large, I would definitely go for stochastic search. Don't know exactly what spinning_plate means when writing that "the neighborhood is not clearly defined". Of course it is --- you either move one item from one set to another, or swap items from two different sets, and this is a simple neighborhood. I would use both operations in stochastic search (which in practice could be tabu search or simulated annealing.)